# Run a php program inside Dropbox

Tags: php, xampp, dropbox

I have begun studying php today and after installing xampp (32 bit windows 7) I opened netbeans and started the classical hello world. Once finished I turned on apache via xampp and tried to execute my program. First I got a

```
Object Not Found Error
```

then I gave the path to my program,

```
http://localhost/C:/Users/zizzo/Dropbox/fraluigab/programming-luigi/php/Index.php
```

which was not the default and I got

```
Access Forbidden Error 403.
```

Now I have two questions: Can I make that my default path instead of simply localhost? And then, how can I get the access allowed to execute my programs?

Thanks

Comment: You need to put the PHP files that you run in to the 'htdocs'/'www' folder within `C:\xampp\`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and look for:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
```

Change to:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/zizzo/Dropbox/"
```

Also look for:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

Change to:

```
<Directory "C:/Users/zizzo/Dropbox/">
```

Then restart the server.

Then you can visit:

```
http://localhost/fraluigab/programming-luigi/php/Index.php
```

Comment: I did as you said (I also run xampp control panel as Administrator) but I still get the Access Forbidden Error.. why is this happening again?

Comment: I got it work but you should edit your answer and add that even the line with starting with <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs needs to be changed accordingly. This line is just below the first DocumentRoot and there is a comment that says you to change the directory as the one of DocumentRoot. No need to run as Administrator. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You should also think about the SQL database if you have one. [Sync XAMPP Data With Dropbox](http://www.pmkelly.com/2012/07/sync-xampp-dropbox/)

Answer (score -2):

```
http://localhost/C:/Users/zizzo/Dropbox/fraluigab/programming-luigi/php/Index.php
```

You can't access directory in that way.
Follow Luigi's answer and also run XAMPP with administrator privilege to avoid any hassles regarding permission